# ScrollView with LinearLayout inside does not work

Tags: android, android-listview, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have a scrollView with two inside LinearLayout but it does not work, the listView does not show all items but only a few. How can I do?

```
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/welcomeView"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_User_welcome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="70"
            android:src="@drawable/user" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/private_area_welcome"
            style="@style/CoopLabel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:text="@string/private_area_welcome" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/welcomeView">       
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/private_area_lists"
        style="@style/CoopLabel"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/private_area_lists" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/privareaList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000" >
    </ListView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/logoutBtn"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/tasto_logout"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

   </RelativeLayout>

   </ScrollView>
```

Comment: `ListView` it self is a scrollable component. You should not add ListView inside ScrollView.

Comment: What all the views your scrollview show, please metion it. And also show the screenshot if possible...

Comment: @MAC but the listView is within a LinearLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommended to use scrollables containing other scrollables - your layout contains ListView inside Scrollview.

You can design your layout as a ListView - you can add header and footer views(welcomeView, logoutBtn, etc..) to the top and bottom of listview - see methods ListView.addHeaderView and addFooterView) - scrolling will be managed by ListView,

or you can replace listview in your original layout with simple LinearLayout and populate it manually row by row(do not forget to assign click listeners to rows etc..) - scrolling will be managed by ScrollView.

To find more information about this problem, try to google "android listview inside scrollview", i am sure it will help you. :-)

Comment: The listView change dynamically, I can't populate it manually, here are other ways?

Comment: If you need to use listview, you can use the first option - listview with header and footer views. Probably it is more effecient, but i think you can also use the second option - you can remove all views from LinearLayout and 'repopulate' it with new items when needed, don't you? :-)